# Fortran subroutine gets stuck (but only when calling via R)

Tags: r, fortran

I have a Fortran subroutine that I converted from someone else's Fortran program. I would like to call this via R's `.Fortran` function. The subroutine works (instantly) when I call it from a Fortan program, but when I try to call it from R, nothing happens (In fact, R is still running this subroutine as I am typing this).

Here is the Fortran program (also containing the subroutine):

```
       PROGRAM blep

       integer a
       real(4) b, c, d

       b = 0.9
       c = 0.1
       d = 0.99
       a = 0

       call midpss(b, c, d, a)

4        format ('Calculated sample size is   ',i6)

       print 4, a
       end







       subroutine midpss(w, x, y, numbr)
c      THIS IS TAKEN FROM "fosgate_original_working.f" AND THEN CONVERTED
          real(8) probA,probB,part1,part2,part3,part4
          real(8) totprA,totprB,factt, resp
          integer numbr
c       character  resp
1       format ('Enter proportion       ',$)
2       format ('Enter error limit      ',$)
3       format ('Enter confidence level ',$)
4       format ('Calculated sample size is   ',i6)
5       format ('Exact mid-P with ',f7.5,' 2-tail probability')
6       format ('Sorry, unable to mathmatically solve this problem.')
7       format ('Reported sample size is not accuarate.')
8       format ('Enter q to quit  ',$)
9       format ('Actual limits for distribution  ',f5.3,' - ',f5.3)
        print *, 'Exact sampleroportions'
        print *, 'Using Mid-P methods'
        print *, 'Geoff Fosgate DVM PhD'
        print *, 'College of Veterinary Medicine'
        print *, 'Texas A&M University'
        print *
10     prop1 = w
             range = x
             conlev = y
c           Convert proportions less than 0.5 for algorithm
       if (prop1 .lt. 0.5) then
        prop = 1 - prop1
        nprop = 1
       else
        prop = prop1
        nprop = 0
       end if
       slimit = max ((prop - range) , 0.0001)
       supper = min ((prop + range) , 0.9999)
c      Probabilities cannot be calculated for p=0 and p=1
       alpha = (1 - conlev)
       if (alpha .gt. 1.0) go to 10
       if (alpha .lt. 0.0) go to 10
       if (prop .gt. 1.0) go to 10
       if (prop .lt. 0.0) go to 10
       numbr = (1 / (1 - prop)) - 1
c      Define and initialize variables
c      Note names of variables based on Fortran 77 rules
c      Starting sample size is based on estimated proportion
c      Resulting sample size must be large enough to obtain this proportion
100    numbr = numbr + 1
       numx = (numbr * prop) + 0.001
c      This is the number of binomial "successes" resulting in the proportion
       if (numx .eq. numbr) go to 100
       if (numx .lt. 1) go to 100
       totprA = slimit**numbr
       totprB = supper**numbr
       do 130 loop1 = numx, (numbr - 1)
c      Must initialize variables within loop
       factt = 1.0
       probA = 0.0
       probB = 0.0
       part1 = 0.0
       part2 = 0.0
       part3 = 0.0
       part4 = 0.0
c      Start loop to calculate factorial component of binomial probability
c      Note that complete factorial calculations not necessary due to cancellations
       do 110 loop2 = (loop1 + 1) , numbr
       factt = factt * (loop2) / (numbr - (loop2 - 1))
110    continue
c      Calculate probability for this particular number of successes
c      Total probability is a running total
c      Note that real variables must have high precision and be comprised
c      of multiple bytes because factorial component can be very large
c      and exponentiated component can be very small
c      Program will fail if any component is recognized as zero or infinity
       part1 = slimit**loop1
       part2 = (1.0-slimit)**(numbr-loop1)
       part3 = supper**loop1
       part4 = (1.0-supper)**(numbr-loop1)
       if (part1 .eq. 0.0) part1 = 1.0D-307
       if (part2 .eq. 0.0) part2 = 1.0D-307
       if (part3 .eq. 0.0) part3 = 1.0D-307
       if (part4 .eq. 0.0) part4 = 1.0D-307
       if (factt .gt. 1.0D308) factt = 1.0D308
       probA = part1 * part2 * factt
       probB = part3 * part4 * factt
       if (loop1 .eq. numx)  then
        totprA = totprA + (0.5 * probA)
        totprB = totprB + (0.5 * probB)
       else
        totprA = totprA + probA
        totprB = totprB + probB
       end if
c      THIS IS ERROR HANDLING. INSTEAD OF PRINTING, SET NUMBR = -1
c      *****************************************************************
       if (probA .eq. 0.0) then 
c        print 6
c        print 7
c        print *
c        go to 150
         numbr = -1
       end if
       if (probB .eq. 0.0) then
c        print 6
c        print 7
c        print *
c        go to 150
         numbr = -1
       end if
c      *****************************************************************
130    continue
140    if ((totprA + (1 - totprB)) .gt. alpha) go to 100
c      go to beginning and increase sample size by 1 if have not
c      reached specified level of confidence

c      I.E. IF INPUT PROPORTION IS LESS THAN 0.5
c      (I DONT THINK THIS IS NECESSARY -- IT JUST PRINTS THE RESULTS)
c150    if (nprop .eq. 1) then
c        print 4,numbr
c        print 9, (1-supper),(1-slimit)
c       else
c        print 4,numbr
c        print 9, slimit,supper
c       end if


c      DO WE NEED THIS PART????
c      *****************************************************************
c       if (totprA+(1-totprB) .lt. alpha) print 5,(totprA+(1-totprB))
c        print *
c        print 8
c        result = resp
c       print *
c      if (resp .ne. 'q') go to 10
c       print *
c       print *
998    return       
999    end
```

(Sorry for the comments left over from my converting the original program to a subroutine).

The program is called `midpss1_prog.f` and the subroutine is called `midpss1.f`

I compile and call the program by doing the following:

```
C:\Users\panterasBox>gfortran midpss1_prog.f

C:\Users\panterasBox>a.exe
 Exact sampleroportions
 Using Mid-P methods
 Geoff Fosgate DVM PhD
 College of Veterinary Medicine
 Texas A&M University

Calculated sample size is       80

C:\Users\panterasBox>
```

This is working just fine!

When I call the subroutine, I do the following:

In the command line, I call this:

```
C:\Users\panterasBox>R CMD SHLIB midpss1.f
gfortran -m64     -O2  -mtune=core2 -c midpss1.f -o midpss1.o
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o midpss1.dll tmp.def midpss1.o -Ld:/RCompil
e/r-compiling/local/local320/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/li
b -lgfortran -LC:/Users/panterasBox/Documents/R/R-3.2.2/bin/x64 -lR
```

Then, I go into the R terminal and do this:

```
> setwd("C:/Users/panterasBox")
> dyn.load("midpss1.dll")
> is.loaded("midpss")
[1] TRUE
> .Fortran("midpss", w=as.numeric(0.9), x=as.numeric(0.1), y=as.numeric(0.90), numbr=as.integer(0))
```

And this last call to `.Fortran` never returns anything. It is just stuck...

Any help figuring out what is going on here would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Could you please look at making your example as minimal as possible whilst still retaining the problem?  Not only would doing so help in your own efforts to resolve the issue, but it's less for us to read.  [If nothing else, delete those huge swathes of commented out code.]  See [mcve].

Comment: In a previous question an answer suggested you use `implicit none`.  You don't have that here, and some of your dummy variables (at the very least) are implicitly declared.  How can we be sure that `real(4)` is the same kind as default real?

Comment: you might be interested in http://www.inside-r.org/node/54298 ...

Comment: @BenBolker This question is actually resulting from my trying to replicate the results from the original author's paper with that function and it failing. Thank you for the relevant reference though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R seems to be sending floating-point numbers to Fortran subroutines as double-precision, so we probably need to declare the corresponding dummy arguments accordingly. Because your program has no `implicit none` at the top of the subroutine, the dummy arguments `w`, `x`, and `y` are regarded implicitly as single-precision, making argument types inconsistent between R and Fortran (so resulting in hung-up). To fix this, simply declare them explicitly (here we assume that `real(8)` corresponds to double precision in R):

```
      subroutine midpss(w, x, y, numbr)
          real(8) :: w, x, y                !<--- insert this line
          !! double precision :: w, x, y    !<--- or this line (but not both)

          !! No need to modify the remaining part...
          ....
```

then we obtain the expected result (on Linux x86_64):

```
> .Fortran("midpss", w=as.numeric(0.9), x=as.numeric(0.1), y=as.numeric(0.99), numbr=as.integer(0))
 Exact sampleroportions
 Using Mid-P methods
 Geoff Fosgate DVM PhD
 College of Veterinary Medicine
 Texas A&M University

$w
[1] 0.9

$x
[1] 0.1

$y
[1] 0.99

$numbr
[1] 80
```

Btw, this kind of problem may be avoided by using `implicit none` (as suggested repeatedly), because all the variables need to be declared explicitly, for example:

```
   subroutine midpss (w, x, y, numbr)
      implicit none
      real(8) :: w, x, y
      real(8) :: prop, prop1, range, conlev, slimit, supper, alpha
      integer :: loop1, loop2, numx, nprop
      ...
```

Comment: There seems to be various pages explaining how floating-point numbers are passed to C/Fortran (for example, https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Foreign.html) and some option seems to be necessary to pass them as single precision.